# When are mailer rake tasks sent with ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailer

My app is using Ruby on Rails mailer to send emails out to users. If I have delayed emails being sent out (e.g. weekly or monthly emails), with 'deliver_later' is there a way for me to know when they are sent? Or are they just added to the queue and sent out at different times, I want to know if there is a way I could check or keep track of when the emails get sent on time. I've tried looking this up and can't find any info on this specific subject. Thanks

Comment: You can specify when a specific email should be sent, see [deliver_later](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery/deliver_later). Or is your question more about querying active jobs and finding out which jobs are enqueued when?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know if there is a way of finding out which jobs are enqueued when